# Нужно найти кол-во троек a, b, c, для которых верно равенство. Почему-то выводит 0, хотя таких троек более 300

Tags: python

```
from itertools import product


k = 0
for a, b, c in product([1, 30], repeat=3):
    if max(a, b) * max(c, 11) == min(a, c) * min(b, 22):
        k += 1
        print(a, b, c)
print(k)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

```
print(*product([1, 30], repeat=3), sep='\n')
```

получаем

```
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 30)
(1, 30, 1)
(1, 30, 30)
(30, 1, 1)
(30, 1, 30)
(30, 30, 1)
(30, 30, 30)
```

какие 300? :)

**вам надо:**

```
for a, b, c in product(range(1, 30), repeat=3):
```